# Database of chess games

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a database of chess games. This might be historical chess games, modern games, or even amateur chess games. Intended to use for academic research and machine learning.

Answer (score 2):

chess.com has a database of downloadable games data:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150809110419/http://www.chess.com:80/downloads/database+of+games

Comment: another resource is here, but many of the links are dead 
http://www.chessopolis.com/chess-game-collections/

Comment: That link now leads to a nice 404 page.

Comment: now it doesn't. wayback machine is your friend